# Flutter web PaintImage() on Mobile Browser error

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

I am trying to get Canvas painted image. It works on web and phone. But when I test it on Mobile Browser the PaintImage() or canvas.drawImage() doesn't work and have error. When I remove PaintImage() it works and I have my canvas image. Anyone had the same problem? Any ideas or other image drawing function for canvas? I can't see the error from debug because you know the Flutter web debugger is poor with reporting. Searching for solution last few days...

```
Future<ui.Image> getCanvasImage() async {
    Size imageSize = const Size(1200, 630);
    final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final canvas = Canvas(recorder,Rect.fromPoints(const Offset(0.0, 0.0), Offset(imageSize.width, imageSize.height)));

    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height),Paint()
          ..shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
              const Offset(0, 0), Offset(imageSize.width, imageSize.height), [
            const Color.fromRGBO(23, 74, 151, 1),
            const Color.fromRGBO(90, 168, 200, 1),
          ]));
    like = await loadUiImage('lib/assets/like.png');
    var rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      100,100,100,100,
    );
    //canvas.drawImageRect(like, maskSourceRect, rect, paint);
    //canvas.drawImage(like, Offset.zero, Paint());
    paintImage(canvas: canvas, rect: rect, image: like, debugImageLabel: 'lake');
    final picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final img =
        picture.toImage(imageSize.width.toInt(), imageSize.height.toInt());
    return img;
  }
}
Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.view(data.buffer), (ui.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone run into similar problems adding --web-renderer canvaskit to the build solved my problem.

Here is how to debug your web on local area to test your Flutter web app on Mobile Browser:

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 8080 --no-sound-null-safety --release --web-renderer canvaskit
```

And from mobile browser enter your pc ip adress with :8080 port.
To see the debug result connect your mobile phone to pc and on Chrome navigator enter chrome://inspect